# How to determine the user started a window session ID

Tags: windows

I cannot use `Get-WmiObject Win32_LoggedOnUser` or `Get-Process` as the remaining process for the session where stated by “SYSTEM” account and not under the account of the user that started the session.

`Query Session` does not show a user for that session ID

Comment: You might get better responses if you describe the scenario you’re dealing with.  How does a user start a session and not have an explorer process running?  How do SYSTEM processes get started under a user session? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Scott, that is the problem. All I have is the session in that state, but it is not clear what happened.
I suspect that it is some program logging on remotely to do a virus scan, backup, or something els.
Knowing who started that session will help me figure this out.

Comment: (1) So, you’re not asking about an ordinary tool for routine use; you’re asking about forensic techniques to investigate a possible cyberattack.  Just explaining that ***in the question*** might give readers a clearer picture of your problem / situation and guide them into a more relevant and useful line of thinking.  (2) Do you require tool(s) that you can use from the command line; i.e., that you can script?  (3) Have you tried looking at the “Users” tab in Task Manager?  (4) Have you tried looking in the Event Log?  (5) Have you tried anything? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.    Consider adding tags like [security] and [forensics].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no PowerShell or WMI query that will give this information. But wtsapi32.dll can give you this information. bellow is a way to run C# code in PowerShell to get this information.

The code uses 32bit API so you will need to run it in PowerShell x86.

The code will display a list of all session states and who started them.

I will maintain the script here:

https://github.com/Guilderm/Windows-Tools/blob/master/SupportScripts.ListSessionInformation.ps1

```
$Source = @'
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace SupportScripts
{
    public class ListSessionInformation
    {
#region Constants
        public const int WTS_CURRENT_SESSION = -1;
#endregion
#region Dll Imports
        [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
        static extern int WTSEnumerateSessions(IntPtr pServer, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int iReserved, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int iVersion, ref IntPtr pSessionInfo, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] ref int iCount);
        [DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool WTSQuerySessionInformation(System.IntPtr pServer, int iSessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS oInfoClass, out System.IntPtr pBuffer, out uint iBytesReturned);
        [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
        static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr pMemory);
#endregion
#region Structures
        //Structure for Terminal Service Client IP Address
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS
        {
            public int iAddressFamily;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
            public byte[] bAddress;
        }
        //Structure for Terminal Service Session Info
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct WTS_SESSION_INFO
        {
            public int iSessionID;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string sWinsWorkstationName;
            public WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS oState;
        }
        //Structure for Terminal Service Session Client Display
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct WTS_CLIENT_DISPLAY
        {
            public int iHorizontalResolution;
            public int iVerticalResolution;
            //1 = The display uses 4 bits per pixel for a maximum of 16 colors.
            //2 = The display uses 8 bits per pixel for a maximum of 256 colors.
            //4 = The display uses 16 bits per pixel for a maximum of 2^16 colors.
            //8 = The display uses 3-byte RGB values for a maximum of 2^24 colors.
            //16 = The display uses 15 bits per pixel for a maximum of 2^15 colors.
            public int iColorDepth;
        }
#endregion
#region Enumurations
        public enum WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS
        {
            WTSActive,
            WTSConnected,
            WTSConnectQuery,
            WTSShadow,
            WTSDisconnected,
            WTSIdle,
            WTSListen,
            WTSReset,
            WTSDown,
            WTSInit
        }
        public enum WTS_INFO_CLASS
        {
            WTSInitialProgram,
            WTSApplicationName,
            WTSWorkingDirectory,
            WTSOEMId,
            WTSSessionId,
            WTSUserName,
            WTSWinStationName,
            WTSDomainName,
            WTSConnectState,
            WTSClientBuildNumber,
            WTSClientName,
            WTSClientDirectory,
            WTSClientProductId,
            WTSClientHardwareId,
            WTSClientAddress,
            WTSClientDisplay,
            WTSClientProtocolType,
            WTSIdleTime,
            WTSLogonTime,
            WTSIncomingBytes,
            WTSOutgoingBytes,
            WTSIncomingFrames,
            WTSOutgoingFrames,
            WTSClientInfo,
            WTSSessionInfo,
            WTSConfigInfo,
            WTSValidationInfo,
            WTSSessionAddressV4,
            WTSIsRemoteSession
        }
#endregion
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr pServer = IntPtr.Zero;
            string sUserName = string.Empty;
            string sDomain = string.Empty;
            string sClientApplicationDirectory = string.Empty;
            string sIPAddress = string.Empty;
            WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS oClientAddres = new WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS();
            WTS_CLIENT_DISPLAY oClientDisplay = new WTS_CLIENT_DISPLAY();
            IntPtr pSessionInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
            int iCount = 0;
            int iReturnValue = WTSEnumerateSessions(pServer, 0, 1, ref pSessionInfo, ref iCount);
            int iDataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (WTS_SESSION_INFO));
            int iCurrent = (int)pSessionInfo;
            if (iReturnValue != 0)
            {
                //Go to all sessions
                for (int i = 0; i < iCount; i++)
                {
                    WTS_SESSION_INFO oSessionInfo = (WTS_SESSION_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure((System.IntPtr)iCurrent, typeof (WTS_SESSION_INFO));
                    iCurrent += iDataSize;
                    uint iReturned = 0;
                    //Get the IP address of the Terminal Services User
                    IntPtr pAddress = IntPtr.Zero;
                    if (WTSQuerySessionInformation(pServer, oSessionInfo.iSessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSClientAddress, out pAddress, out iReturned) == true)
                    {
                        oClientAddres = (WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pAddress, oClientAddres.GetType());
                        sIPAddress = oClientAddres.bAddress[2] + "." + oClientAddres.bAddress[3] + "." + oClientAddres.bAddress[4] + "." + oClientAddres.bAddress[5];
                    }
                    //Get the User Name of the Terminal Services User
                    if (WTSQuerySessionInformation(pServer, oSessionInfo.iSessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSUserName, out pAddress, out iReturned) == true)
                    {
                        sUserName = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pAddress);
                    }
                    //Get the Domain Name of the Terminal Services User
                    if (WTSQuerySessionInformation(pServer, oSessionInfo.iSessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSDomainName, out pAddress, out iReturned) == true)
                    {
                        sDomain = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pAddress);
                    }
                    //Get the Display Information  of the Terminal Services User
                    if (WTSQuerySessionInformation(pServer, oSessionInfo.iSessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSClientDisplay, out pAddress, out iReturned) == true)
                    {
                        oClientDisplay = (WTS_CLIENT_DISPLAY)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pAddress, oClientDisplay.GetType());
                    }
                    //Get the Application Directory of the Terminal Services User
                    if (WTSQuerySessionInformation(pServer, oSessionInfo.iSessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSClientDirectory, out pAddress, out iReturned) == true)
                    {
                        sClientApplicationDirectory = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pAddress);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Session ID : " + oSessionInfo.iSessionID);
                    Console.WriteLine("Session State : " + oSessionInfo.oState);
                    Console.WriteLine("User Name : " + sDomain + @"\" + sUserName);
                    Console.WriteLine("Workstation Name : " + oSessionInfo.sWinsWorkstationName);
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("IP Address : " + sIPAddress);
                    Console.WriteLine("Client Display Resolution: " + oClientDisplay.iHorizontalResolution + " x " + oClientDisplay.iVerticalResolution);
                    Console.WriteLine("Client Display Colour Depth: " + oClientDisplay.iColorDepth);
                    Console.WriteLine("Client Application Directory: " + sClientApplicationDirectory);
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("-----End of Session Info-----");
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
                WTSFreeMemory(pSessionInfo);
            }
        }
    }
}
'@


Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp
[SupportScripts.ListSessionInformation]::Main($null)



    $Source = @'
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    public class Program
    {
    #region Constants
        public const int WTS_CURRENT_SESSION = -1;
    #endregion
    #region Dll Imports
        [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
        static extern int WTSEnumerateSessions(IntPtr pServer, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int iReserved, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int iVersion, ref IntPtr pSessionInfo, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] ref int iCount);
        [DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool WTSQuerySessionInformation(System.IntPtr pServer, int iSessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS oInfoClass, out System.IntPtr pBuffer, out uint iBytesReturned);
        [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
        static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr pMemory);
    #endregion
    #region Structures
        //Structure for Terminal Service Client IP Address
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS
        {
            public int iAddressFamily;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
            public byte[] bAddress;
        }

        //Structure for Terminal Service Session Info
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct WTS_SESSION_INFO
        {
            public int iSessionID;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string sWinsWorkstationName;
            public WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS oState;
        }

        //Structure for Terminal Service Session Client Display
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct WTS_CLIENT_DISPLAY
        {
            public int iHorizontalResolution;
            public int iVerticalResolution;
            //1 = The display uses 4 bits per pixel for a maximum of 16 colors.
            //2 = The display uses 8 bits per pixel for a maximum of 256 colors.
            //4 = The display uses 16 bits per pixel for a maximum of 2^16 colors.
            //8 = The display uses 3-byte RGB values for a maximum of 2^24 colors.
            //16 = The display uses 15 bits per pixel for a maximum of 2^15 colors.
            public int iColorDepth;
        }

    #endregion
    #region Enumurations
        public enum WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS
        {
            WTSActive,
            WTSConnected,
            WTSConnectQuery,
            WTSShadow,
            WTSDisconnected,
            WTSIdle,
            WTSListen,
            WTSReset,
            WTSDown,
            WTSInit
        }

        public enum WTS_INFO_CLASS
        {
            WTSInitialProgram,
            WTSApplicationName,
            WTSWorkingDirectory,
            WTSOEMId,
            WTSSessionId,
            WTSUserName,
            WTSWinStationName,
            WTSDomainName,
            WTSConnectState,
            WTSClientBuildNumber,
            WTSClientName,
            WTSClientDirectory,
            WTSClientProductId,
            WTSClientHardwareId,
            WTSClientAddress,
            WTSClientDisplay,
            WTSClientProtocolType,
            WTSIdleTime,
            WTSLogonTime,
            WTSIncomingBytes,
            WTSOutgoingBytes,
            WTSIncomingFrames,
            WTSOutgoingFrames,
            WTSClientInfo,
            WTSSessionInfo,
            WTSConfigInfo,
            WTSValidationInfo,
            WTSSessionAddressV4,
            WTSIsRemoteSession
        }

    #endregion
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr pServer = IntPtr.Zero;
            string sUserName = string.Empty;
            string sDomain = string.Empty;
            string sClientApplicationDirectory = string.Empty;
            string sIPAddress = string.Empty;
            WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS oClientAddres = new WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS();
            WTS_CLIENT_DISPLAY oClientDisplay = new WTS_CLIENT_DISPLAY();
            IntPtr pSessionInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
            int iCount = 0;
            int iReturnValue = WTSEnumerateSessions(pServer, 0, 1, ref pSessionInfo, ref iCount);
            int iDataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (WTS_SESSION_INFO));
            int iCurrent = (int)pSessionInfo;
            if (iReturnValue != 0)
            {
                //Go to all sessions
                for (int i = 0; i < iCount; i++)
                {
                    WTS_SESSION_INFO oSessionInfo = (WTS_SESSION_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure((System.IntPtr)iCurrent, typeof (WTS_SESSION_INFO));
                    iCurrent += iDataSize;
                    uint iReturned = 0;
                    //Get the IP address of the Terminal Services User
                    IntPtr pAddress = IntPtr.Zero;
                    if (WTSQuerySessionInformation(pServer, oSessionInfo.iSessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSClientAddress, out pAddress, out iReturned) == true)
                    {
                        oClientAddres = (WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pAddress, oClientAddres.GetType());
                        sIPAddress = oClientAddres.bAddress[2] + "." + oClientAddres.bAddress[3] + "." + oClientAddres.bAddress[4] + "." + oClientAddres.bAddress[5];
                    }

                    //Get the User Name of the Terminal Services User
                    if (WTSQuerySessionInformation(pServer, oSessionInfo.iSessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSUserName, out pAddress, out iReturned) == true)
                    {
                        sUserName = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pAddress);
                    }

                    //Get the Domain Name of the Terminal Services User
                    if (WTSQuerySessionInformation(pServer, oSessionInfo.iSessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSDomainName, out pAddress, out iReturned) == true)
                    {
                        sDomain = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pAddress);
                    }

                    //Get the Display Information  of the Terminal Services User
                    if (WTSQuerySessionInformation(pServer, oSessionInfo.iSessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSClientDisplay, out pAddress, out iReturned) == true)
                    {
                        oClientDisplay = (WTS_CLIENT_DISPLAY)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pAddress, oClientDisplay.GetType());
                    }

                    //Get the Application Directory of the Terminal Services User
                    if (WTSQuerySessionInformation(pServer, oSessionInfo.iSessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSClientDirectory, out pAddress, out iReturned) == true)
                    {
                        sClientApplicationDirectory = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pAddress);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Session ID : " + oSessionInfo.iSessionID);
                    Console.WriteLine("Session State : " + oSessionInfo.oState);
                    Console.WriteLine("User Name : " + sDomain + @"\" + sUserName);
                    Console.WriteLine("Workstation Name : " + oSessionInfo.sWinsWorkstationName);
                    Console.WriteLine("IP Address : " + sIPAddress);
                    Console.WriteLine("Client Display Resolution: " + oClientDisplay.iHorizontalResolution + " x " + oClientDisplay.iVerticalResolution);
                    Console.WriteLine("Client Display Colour Depth: " + oClientDisplay.iColorDepth);
                    Console.WriteLine("Client Application Directory: " + sClientApplicationDirectory);
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");
                }

                WTSFreeMemory(pSessionInfo);
            }
        }
    }
    '@


    Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp
    [Program]::Main("")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tasklist -v
```

If you use it with powershell...

```
tasklist -v | select-string "UserNameYoureLookingFor"
```

Comment: Thank you Eddie, but `tasklist -v` will only shows "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" for the remaining services